# Dynamically retrieve values of a data type

Tags: haskell, generic-programming

I'm using the [Data.Data](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Data.html) module to dynamically grab some data of a data type at runtime. Let's say a have a data type like `data Place = Place {name :: Text, description :: Text} deriving (Data)`:

- I could retrieve its constructor with [toConstr](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Data.html#v:toConstr) `toConstr (Place "Some place" "Bla")` which will give me `Place`
- I could retrieve its label fields with [constrFields](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Data.html#v:constrFields) `constrFields $ toConstr (Place "Some place" "Bla")` which will give me `["name", "description"]`

Now what I need is to get the values with which I constructed the Place, so for `Place "Some place" "Bla"` I want to extract something like `["Some place", "Bla"]`, the catch being that in my code **I don't know that this data value is a `Place`**, it could be any data type that derives the `Data` class. Icn code:

```
getValuesOfDataValue :: (Data a) => a -> [String]
getValuesOfDataValue a =
    -- some magic generic function

data Place = Place {name :: Text, description :: Text} deriving (Data)
 -- the code below should evaluate to ["Some place", "Bla"]
getValuesOfDataValue (Place "Some place" "Bla")

data SomeType = SomeType {num :: Integer, num2 :: Integer} deriving (Data)
 -- the code below should evaluate to [300, 500]
getValuesOfDataValue (SomeType 300 500)
```

How can I accomplish this?

Note: `getValuesOfDataValue` doesn't have to return exactly a [String] type, it just need to have the values packed in something.

Comment: Please give more/better code. Top-level `let`s aren't legal Haskell, and it's not clear what `constrFields` is supposed to do. It would also help both of us if you gave types for `p`, `c`, etc.

Comment: Take a look at `gfoldl`.

Comment: Please, add some valid Haskell code that describes the problem you are facing.

Comment: I really don't get the comments asking for valid code since the one that I provided is just to conceptualize the question, you could consider it pseudo-haskell. Did you guys didn't get the question that is stated in the last paragraph? Apparently PyRulez understood it perfectly well. Anyway I'm going to edit and improve the question.

Comment: @PyRulez if you could provided some very simple example I would appreciate, anyway I will take a look since it appears to be what I'm looking for, thanx ;)

Comment: @Eric I edited the question, hope it's clear now.

Comment: @RodrigoRibeiro same as the comment above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `cast` from the `Typeable` family (recall that `Data` is a subclass of `Typeable`).

```
λ> import Data.Text
λ> import Data.Data
λ> :set -XDeriveDataTypeable -XOverloadedStrings
λ> data Triple = Triple Text Text Int deriving (Show, Data)
λ> gmapQ cast (Triple "a" "b" 1821) :: [Maybe Text]
[Just "a",Just "b",Nothing]
λ> gmapQ cast (Triple "a" "b" 1821) :: [Maybe Int]
[Nothing,Nothing,Just 1821]
```

Take that, dynamically typed programming languages.

If you don't know which type you want in advance, you can also stringify the values with `gshow` from the `syb` package:

```
λ> :set -package syb
λ> import Data.Generics.Text
λ> data Triple = Triple Text Text Int deriving (Data)
λ> gmapQ gshow (Triple "a" "b" 1821)
["(pack \"a\")","(pack \"b\")","(1821)"]
```

I'll warn you though: not knowing which type you want in advance severely limits what you can do with generics. Not everything can be stringified and even when they are it's ugly (as seen above). Even knowing a whitelist of what types you want will aid you substantially:

```
λ> import Control.Arrow
λ> :set -XScopedTypeVariables
λ> let show' (proxy :: Proxy a) = Kleisli (\x -> show <$> (cast x :: Maybe a))
λ> gmapQ (runKleisli (show' (Proxy :: Proxy Int) <+> show' (Proxy :: Proxy Text))) (Triple "a" "b" 1821)
["a","b","1821"]
```

> Note: getValuesOfDataValue doesn't have to return exactly a [String] type, it just need to have the values packed in something.

The question is what to pack it in. The way `gshow` works is that it recursively calls `gmapQ` (and its helper `extQ`, which is built from `gmapQ` and `cast`) on the `Data a => a` value:

```
-- | Generic show: an alternative to \"deriving Show\"
gshow :: Data a => a -> String
gshow x = gshows x ""

-- | Generic shows
gshows :: Data a => a -> ShowS

-- This is a prefix-show using surrounding "(" and ")",
-- where we recurse into subterms with gmapQ.
gshows = ( \t ->
                showChar '('
              . (showString . showConstr . toConstr $ t)
              . (foldr (.) id . gmapQ ((showChar ' ' .) . gshows) $ t)
              . showChar ')'
         ) `extQ` (shows :: String -> ShowS)
```

It has a base case of `String -> ShowS` so whenever it hits a string it knows to return it and terminate. Without knowing more details about your problem domain, I would say to you to go out and build your own `gshows` using the same strategy. In the very general case where you want to pack *every* type, there can be no answer, but perhaps something specific exists for your particular task.

Comment: It works, but having to specify the types (:: [Maybe anything]) will bring another level of complication since I'll have to dynamically find those (remember that the code has no clue that is dealing with a `Triple` or anything else). Anyway thx ;)